# Secure distributed storing and querying of [medical] data?

Tags: encryption, databases, disk-encryption, file-system, distributed-computing

Comparing  ways of distributing and securely storing and querying structured and schemaless data.

Currently I am using MongoDB, but am looking into (Postgres|MySQL)&CryptDB, Cassandra and others.

What do I need to keep in mind, for securely storing and expressively querying [potentially] massive data?

Comment: It depends what you mean by secure. Who is the adversary?

Comment: External hackers, data-centre owners (worst case scenario: [ensuring privacy and integrity in the untrusted cloud](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~arielfel/pub/ajf-dissertation.pdf)) and authorised non-administrative users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with MongoDB, and will setup:

- 256-bit encryption of database filesystem (GridFS)
- TLS between database servers and applications servers
- TLS between application servers and consumers
- User authentication on the application servers (scrypt for password, expiring tokens for login, x509 certs required for generating+using `client_id`, `client_secret`)
- User authentication on the database servers
- Internal message-passing queue

  - Two-time use username+password should be generated and stored in encrypted database.
  - Password used to encrypt message payload, username added into header.
  - Popping message hits database for password, which is then used to decrypt payload.

Frontends consuming my RESTful API can add another level of security: encrypting data before it hits my application and database servers. HIPAA and other compliance will also be checked before opening for beta testing.